# Controlling volume of W8's Music app independently

Tags: windows-8

I was wondering whether it is possible to control the volume of the Music App in Windows 8 independently from system's sounds. It is quite annoying that the Charms Bar in the Music App controls the system's volume.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find any option in Volume Mixer as well

Comment: I think its not possible. refs :[How do we control the Music App's volume?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/028fabe1-c4b4-4704-aabb-6150914e0104/), ["There’s no way to control the volume of individual Metro-style apps"](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-tip-adjusting-volume-143410)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the metro-style applications which play sounds implement the **[ISimpleAudioVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** interface.
It **is allowed** to set a session-wise volume, but only if the developer had made use of it in that manner.

From the documentation:

> Typical audio applications do not modify the volume levels of
>   sessions. Instead, they rely on users to set these volume levels
>   through the **Sndvol** program. **Sndvol** modifies only the master volume
>   levels of sessions. By default, the session manager sets the master
>   volume level to 1.0 at the initial activation of a session. Subsequent
>   volume changes by Sndvol or other clients are persistent across
>   computer restarts.

Hence, unfortunately, unless the application itself has implemented session-wise controls, you are out of luck in this regard,

Comment: ok.. I'm a massive windows 8 fan but this is pretty lame, do xbox music protected files work in other media players that actually allow you to control the level of music?